# Apache Virtual Host (Subdomain) access with different computer on LAN

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am currently trying to configure the Virtual Host (Subdomain) of my Apache HTTP Server so it can be accessed with another computer on my LAN. The current setup of Apache with PHP and MySQL works locally on the same physical machine.

So I have two Virtual Host setup (development and cms) running on a non-default port of 50080. The machine of the server have a IP of 10.0.0.10. From the same physical machine, I can access the two Virtual Host using:

```
development.localhost:50080
cms.localhost:50080
```

From a different physical machine, I can access the root of the server using:

```
10.0.0.10:50080
```

But I cannot or do not know how to access the Virtual Host from the different machine. I tried something like:

```
development.10.0.0.10:50080
cms.10.0.0.10:50080
```

But they do not seem to work.

Here's how my `httpd-vhosts` file looks like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:50080
<VirtualHost *:50080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/HTTP"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:50080>
    ServerAdmin administrator@development.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/HTTP/development"
    ServerName development.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/development.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/development.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I read some of the other post here and the Apache forum, but there's not exact case for this.

I was wondering how I can access the Virtual Host (Subdomain) from another machine and keep the same port if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, here are the configuration if anyone else is looking for this:

==================================================================================

> Machine A (Apache HTTP Server):
>   httpd-vhost:

```
NameVirtualHost *:50080

<VirtualHost *:50080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/HTTP"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias alias <!-- Added -->
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:50080>
    ServerAdmin administrator@development.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/HTTP/development"
    ServerName development.localhost
    ServerAlias development.phoenix <!-- Added -->
    ErrorLog "logs/development.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/development.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

> hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 development.localhost

127.0.0.1 alias
127.0.0.1 development.alias
```

==================================================================================

> Machine B (Guest Machine):
>   hosts:

```
10.0.0.10 alias
10.0.0.10 development.alias
```

From the second machine, you should be able to access with "alias" and "development.alias"

Comment: Many thanks for this, was a great help! A couple of side notes for anyone that's still having trouble with this:
where "phoenix" is written above, I used alias and it worked (not sure why phoenix was used when alias is everywhere else...)
Also You may need to create a rule for your local firewall on the port you are using before you see your website over the network. I had to create an exception for port 80 (I didn't use 50080)

Comment: You could also add mod_proxy and then ProxyPass /dev http://development.localhost/ and ProxyReversePass /dev http://development.localhost/ and then use http://public-ip/dev/

Comment: Is it possible to do this without editing the client's host file?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest making the following change (add the ServerAlias lines):

```
NameVirtualHost *:50080
<VirtualHost *:50080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/HTTP"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias cms.myserver.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:50080>
    ServerAdmin administrator@development.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/HTTP/development"
    ServerName development.localhost 
    ServerAlias development.myserver.com
    ErrorLog "logs/development.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/development.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache to ensure the changes take effect.

Then on your second computer you need to add a custom dns entry for these new domain names. If it is Windows, edit the file `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. If it is Linux, edit /etc/hosts. Either way add:

```
10.0.0.10 development.myserver.com
10.0.0.10 cms.myserver.com
```

Now on your second computer you should be able to access the following URLs:

```
http://development.myserver.com:50080
http://cms.myserver.com:50080
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error when trying to start Apache with the configuration you gave...

Comment: I am getting an error while trying to start Apache, so it seem to the configuration with the httpd-vhosts file.

BTW, the first <VirtualHost> entry is pointing to the root of the directory, I did not add  the "cms" entry since I figure it be the same as the "development" entry

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, you'll need to either set up DNS entries, or add entries to the /etc/hosts file of each computer accessing the server.

`localhost` is an entry that exists in everyone's /etc/hosts file by default, always pointing to 127.0.0.1. Without adding a /etc/hosts entry, `developer.localhost` doesn't exist, and prefixing an ip address with a subdomain won't work at all.

Comment: My hosts file on the Apache machine have the entry:
127.0.0.1 development.localhost
The second machine have nothing yet, what should I add?

Answer (score 1):

Using a SSH + Putty tunnel, and thus having a 127.0.0.1 on my server, I managed to access my subdomains by doing the following on my server side:

```
# nano /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1  sub1.domain.com sub2.domain.com sub3.domain.com sub4.domain.com
```

I did not change the host file of the remote computer, and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

For `Named Virtual Hosts` you need to use a hostname or domainname to connect to you apache server. It does not work with ips.

You could insert an entry in your `/etc/hosts` on your second system.

Comment: My hosts file on the Apache machine have the entry:
127.0.0.1 development.localhost
The second machine have nothing yet, what should I add?

Comment: `<ip of development server> development.server` for example, and then add the `ServerAlias development.server` to your apache config.