# Android: HTTP connection to localhost web site

Tags: android, http

I am developing a tablet application which needs to connect to a web site to collect online content.

I have seen that we can indeed connect to a web server on a local system by addressing it via it's IP address.

However, I am using virtual hosts on my system, so as to use virtual domains.

This is setup on my system in the apache `httpd-vhosts.conf` file like this -

```
#
# Project wordpress dev site
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/web/www/boutique"
    ServerName boutique.project.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

with my hosts file having the following entry

```
127.0.0.1        boutique.project.dev        # project woocommerce site
```

I am using the `HttpPost` and `HttpClient` classes and I cannot see how I can provide the real IP address whilst still transmitting the host name in the URL request.

So, what I need to know is how can I make queries from my application using the virtual address `" boutique.project.dev "` ?

Is this possible ?

---

Edit :

Following one comment, I need to make things more clearer.

I am wanting to do this in **code**.  Each time we make a connection to a site, the URL does a DNS lookup to determine the IP address to use.  I need to intercept this and provide the IP address of my local system.  I have seen some examples for proxy's using `HttpHost`, but I am unclear as to how to use this or even if it is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution which I hope will avoid some useless "banging the head against a wall" for those of you who might have the same need.

Two or three steps are necessary.

1st step : Open the firewall to allow connections.

- This is obviously necessary or else, whatever you do the connection will not be made.  I use Comodo and so I added a rule in the firewall permitting all connections coming from the local LAN.

2nd step : Tell your server, apache in my case, to listen on its IP address.

- I added the following entry in my `httpd.conf` file :

  Listen [*my ip address*]:80

3rd step : Code the connection

The key to getting this to work is to tell which virtual server is needed.  So, without further boring details, here is the code :

```
// setup the needed objects
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
// create the request using the IP address of the server machine
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://[target ip address]:80/testpage.php");
// here is the code magic - manually set the host header
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.HOST, "boutique.project.dev");
// now execute the request
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
// read back the response as normal
....
```

The result is that the apache server will map the request to the virtual host.

I hope this will be useful for others here !

---

Oh, I almost forgot, don't forget to enable the WiFi on your tablet - can save hours of wondering why it doesn't work !

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't do that unless you modify host file in android device (with root permissions)

This is a similar question: [Apache Virtual Host (Subdomain) access with different computer on LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141634/apache-virtual-host-subdomain-access-with-different-computer-on-lan)

You also could setup a DNS server in your computer (i.e bind9) and set entries for your apache virtualhost and configure android in order to use that DNS server.

Comment: As each time a connection is made to a URL there is a DNS lookup which returns the corresponding IP address, I am looking for the means to override the DNS lookup within my code, as opposed to changing the tablets setup.  I will edit my question to make this more clearer.